# C# DebuggerStepThrough Usage

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Is there any performance or resource overhead in keeping **using System.Diagnostics** and **DebuggerStepThrough** attributes in code that is compiled into production?  Is it bad team practice to push these attributes into a repo branch shared by others, if their addition is your preference for debugging?  Finally, I have seen this variation of the attribute in auto generated code: `[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]`.  Is this format more concise in regard to what is used from System Diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

There won't be any performance issue because it has nothing to do with CLR. Below is the microsoft documentation that describes the DebuggerStepThroughAttribute. Hope this helps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute?view=net-6.0